# Vue.prototype vs Vue.use vs import for each file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

These are some of the ways I know to create a global function to vue js project:

**time.js**

```
// if Vue.use()

export default {
  install: Vue => {
    Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, "time", {
       return new Date().getTime();
    })
  }
}

// else 

function time () {
  return new Date().getTime();
}

export { time }
```

**main.js**

```
...

import { time } from "time";

// if Vue.prototyp
Vue.prototype.$time = time 

// else if Vue.use()
Vue.use(time)

...
```

**App.vue**

```
// if Vue.prototype or Vue.use()
console.log(this.$time());

// else 
import { time } from "time";
console.log(time());
```

What is the best method for vue js project?

Answer (score 1):

Use `import` rather than polluting the global scope.
You will not benefit from tree-shaking, will probably have collisions, it's harder to debug and probably some other drawbacks that I cannot think about right now.